# Highchart line chart with vertical line between values

Tags: highcharts

We need a line chart where each point is not connected by a straight line, but a horizontal line from one value to the next, followed by a vertical line to pick up the new value. The picture below shows what I want.
[image]

Which chart type can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the line chart, but add the required values to form the line that you need

for example:

```
 data: [[0,3], [1,3], [1,4], [2,4], [2,2], [3,2], [3,5], [4,5], [4,0]]
```

get you this:
[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvzgyew2/3/)